# Issue passing id into url attempting fetch in Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to get the user post from jsonplaceholder. I get the user id from the users endpoint, and from there I'm trying to go to the user posts endpoint. With the 'print(context)' that is in views.py I correctly get the json data of the user I passed in the 'all_users' view, but I'm getting

```
NoReverseMatch at /users/1/
Reverse for 'user' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/(?P<id>[^/]+)/$']
```

views.py

```
def user(request, id):
    response = requests.get(placeholder_url + 'users/' + str(id) + '/posts')
    user = response.json()
    context = {
        'user': user
    }
    print(context)
    return render(request, 'user.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', all_users, name='users'),
    path('users/<str:id>/', user, name='user')
]
```

users.html

```
{% for user in users %} 
<h5 class="card-title"> {{ user.name }}
<a href="{% url 'user' user.id %}" >See Posts</a> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `{% url 'user' user.id %}` ... here if user is a model... then id won't be string... it will be integer...

Comment: its not from a model, its fetched from the jsonplaceholder api. If I change in urls to  'users/<int:id>/' I get the same result.

Comment: can you show me the `user.html` file? the problem is in there. you have an url template tag in `user.html` that causes the problem.

Comment: in user.html I just have a h1 tag. And this is the for loop I have in users.html
{% for user in users %}
                   <h5 class="card-title"> {{ user.name }}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'user' user.id %}" >See Posts</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            {% endfor %}